# Javascript - Fastest way to show and hide lots of list items with in two independent UL items on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two bid UL elements on the same page and I would like each to show a maximum of 5 list items. Then, they would  hide the others that can be seen if a user wanted to by clicking the "See more" li element which is dynamically created by the Javascript.

suppose these below are my "ul" set of elements.

```
    <ul class="setOne">
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="setTwo">
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
       <li>List item 1</li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my JS code I have been using;

```
    $('.setOne').each(function(){ 
    var max = 2;
    if ($(this).find('li').length > max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="viewmore"><span class="showMore">View more</span><span class="showLess less">Hide</span></li>');

        $('.viewmore').click( function(){
            $(this).siblings(':gt('+max+')').toggle().end().find('span').toggle();
        });

    }else if ($(this).find('li').length === max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="nomore"><span class="End">End</span></li>');
    }else if ($(this).find('li').length < max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="nomore"><span class="End">No Likes</span></li>');
    }

});
```

I wanted to select all the two `ul` elements by using `$('ul')`, but it only works for the last `ul` element.

Comment: You want to use `$('ul')` - then use it. I can only see `$('.setOne')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066320/javascript-fastest-way-to-show-and-hide-lots-of-list-items?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with jquery

Live Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/LhVcc/

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `$('ul')` selector then, and make sure you don't bind `$('.viewmore')` twice by adding context:

```
$('ul').each(function(){ 
    var max = 2;
    if ($(this).children('li').length > max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="viewmore"><span class="showMore">View more</span><span class="showLess less">Hide</span></li>');

        $('.viewmore', this).on('click',  function(){
            $(this).siblings(':gt('+max+')').toggle().end().find('span').toggle();
        });

    }else if ($(this).find('li').length == max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="nomore"><span class="End">End</span></li>');
    }else if ($(this).find('li').length < max) {
        $(this).find('li:gt('+max+')').hide().end().append('<li class="nomore"><span class="End">No Likes</span></li>');
    }
}); ​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyzyU/)

Comment: Hey adeneo, thanks for the correction but i still have a slight problem with the second "else if" statement. With only 3 list items, the "show more " gets shown yet with 3 list items means `max = 2`.

Comment: well, no! with three list items you have three elements, and that's above the max, which is two, so of course the "show more" gets shown ?